# Does enabling Enhanced Dictation in Mac dictation improve the speech recognition accuracy?

Tags: voice-dictation

In [Mac Dictation](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5449), I wonder whether enabling  Enhanced Dictation impacts the speech recognition accuracy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that link, it affects only speed, duration & offline ability, not accuracy.

It downloads the database locally to your machine, allowing the Mac itself to do the work, rather than having to send it to Apple.

Presumably, though it's not mentioned, the learning accuracy will still improve over time, as it learns from its mistakes.